# Javascript only loaded first time or upon refresh

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm building a cross-platform app with Cordova and jQuery Mobile 1.4.5, i have a simple `html` page which should load a `javascript` file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">

        <!-- Include jQUERY --->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom-icons.css">
        <script src="jquery/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>

        <title>myPage</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- jQUERY HEADER is a navigation bar with multiple options -->
        <div data-role="header">
            <a href="index.html" class="ui-btn ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-left">Home</a>
            <h1>my app</h1>
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul id="nav-bar">
                    <li><a href="a.html" data-page="a">a</a></li>
                    <li><a href="b.html" data-page="b">b</a></li>
                    <li><a href="c.html" data-page="c">c</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

       <div role="main" class="ui-content">
           <center><h3><i>A title</i></h3>

           <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
                <legend>my legend</legend>
                <input type="checkbox" data-role="flipswitch" name="flip1" id="flip1">
                <input type="checkbox" data-role="flipswitch" name="flip2" id="flip2">
                <input type="checkbox" data-role="flipswitch" name="flip3" id="flip3">
                <input type="checkbox" data-role="flipswitch" name="flip4" id="flip4">
           </fieldset>
           </center>
       </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/home.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, the `home.js` file is only loaded the first time (or upon refresh), but if i am for example on `b.html` and i navigate to the above page (`index.html`) then `home.js` is not executed.

The home `home.js` file simply contains `console.log("executed");` , which is printed when cordova loads the `index.html` file but not when i later manually navigate to that page through the navigation bar.

EDIT : Note that other pages don't show this behaviour.
For example the below page always loads the javascript file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css"> -->

        <!-- Include jQUERY --->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom-icons.css">
        <script src="jquery/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>

        <title>bla bla</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- jQUERY HEADER is a navigation bar with multiple options -->
        <div data-role="header">
            <a href="index.html" class="ui-btn ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-left">Home</a>
            <h1>smartHub</h1>
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul id="nav-bar">
                    <li><a href="a.html" data-page="a">a</a></li>
                    <li><a href="b.html" data-page="b">b</a></li>
                    <li><a href="c.html" data-page="c">c</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed-icon="carat-d" data-expanded-icon="carat-u">
          <h1>...</h1>
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false">
                ...
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed-icon="carat-d" data-expanded-icon="carat-u">
          <h1>...</h1>
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false">
                ...
            </ul>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/someOtherFile.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT : I "fixed" the problem by changing the link to the home page in the header to this `<a href="#" id="homeButton" class="ui-btn ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-left">Home</a>` and then putting an on click handler for the home button like this :

```
$("#homeButton").on("click", function() {
    window.location.replace("index.html"); 
});
```

Doing this is equivalent to really browsing to the page. However, i don't consider this to be a proper solution. It would be nice if someone can point out why my home page exhibits this behavior.

Furthermore, this actually isn't a solution at all since it seems that items i've put in `localStorage` are lost when redirecting to `index.html`...

**EDIT: I reproduced the problem as simple as possible.**
The reproduction contains two html files which can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzEb6HZK4RZZRXVEUDFHZGl5U2M).
When browsing to `index.html` it prints `On index.html`, then we can use the navigation bar to go to `a.html` which will print `On page a.html`. If we then go to the index again by clicking the home button it won't print `On index.html` anymore (hence the script is not executed), while if we  navigate to `a.html` again, it will print `On page a.html` (hence, that script is executed every time we navigate to the page while the script on the index page doesn't).

Comment: Do `b.html` contain the same HTML?

Comment: @fzzle `b.html` contains the same header but of course has a different body and includes a different javascript file.

Comment: Could the down voter at least be constructive? What's the reason for this?

Comment: Am I right when I think your app is not a single-page application? If so, why are you not including cordova.js in the other pages? (asking because that seems to be the difference between the files)

Comment: @RonaldPK Indeed, my app is not a single-page application. I'm not sure but i think that `cordova.js` needs to be loaded only once, else it gives rise to the error `Error: cordova already defined`.

Comment: @HyperZ One of the key features of JQ Mobile is that it hijacks links and turns them into Ajax requests, injecting the requested page into the DOM. Which means your app is a single-page application... You may need to have the code in `home.js` executed after the `pagecreate` event has fired.

Comment: @RonaldPK Thanks, didn't know that! First time i'm using jQuery Mobile to build an app. I'm going to try that, will keep you in touch :)

Comment: @HyperZ I'd also recommend putting `cordova.js` in the `<head>`.

Comment: @RonaldPK Thanks, i've put that in `head` now. I also tried using the `pagecreate` event so now the page create event is fired every time i navigate to "another" page except for the index page... So when i navigate to `a.html` or `b.html` or ... the pagecreate event is fired, but not when i navigate to `index.html`. This is really driving me crazy..

Comment: @RonaldPK I added a simple and minimal example which shows the same behavior. Hopefully we can figure this out :)

Comment: @HyperZ You may need to read up on the workings of jQuery Mobile... I've posted an answer that should get you going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery Mobile `index.html` becomes a container for all pages in your app. So when the user navigates to `a.html`, its content is injected into the DOM already created for `index.html`. Script in `index.html` remains active. `index.html` content remains in the DOM but is hidden. When the user navigates back to `index.html`, the content of `index.html` simply becomes visible again. The content of `a.html` is removed from the DOM.

When the user then navigates to `a.html` again, its content will again be injected into the DOM, executing any script inside it again.

Take these pages and watch the console.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>  
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- Include jQUERY -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

        <title>Index page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="index">
            <div data-role="header">
                <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-left">Home</a>
                <h1>My app title</h1>
                <div data-role="navbar">
                    <ul id="nav-bar">
                        <li><a href="a.html" data-page="a">a</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-page="b">b</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-page="c">c</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

           <div role="main" class="ui-content">
               <h3><i>Some title</i></h3>
           </div>

            <script>
                console.log("On index.html");
            </script>
        </div>
        <script>
            $(document).on('pageshow', function() {
                // catch the ID of the active page
                var curID = $('.ui-page-active').attr('id');
                console.log("curID: " + curID);
                switch (curID) {
                    // code here
                    default: break;
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

a.html:

```
<html>
    <head>  
        <!-- Note: no need to re-include the jQM-files. They're already around. -->
        <title>Other page page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="pageA">
            <div data-role="header">
                <a href="index.html" class="ui-btn ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-left">Home</a>
                <h1>My app title</h1>
                <div data-role="navbar">
                    <ul id="nav-bar">
                        <li><a href="a.html" data-page="a">a</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-page="b">b</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-page="c">c</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

           <div role="main" class="ui-content">
               <p>Page a</p>
           </div>
            <script>
                console.log("On page a.html");
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note that I've added DIVs with `data-role="page"` and with unique IDs in both files.

The `pageshow` event handler is key. It is triggered every time jQM shows a 'page'. (There can be multiple elements in `index.html` with `data-role="page"`, they're all treated as 'pages').

Comment: Thanks, i just figured it out while talking with a college about an hour ago. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is a caching problem, you can use versioning for your JS file:

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/home.js?version=1.0.0.5"></script>
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more explicit? I'm not into web development. What will this do exactly? Do i always need to send a new random version number if i don't want the file to be cached?

Comment: If you are developing and actively edit the file, you can put versioning (if caching on) or you can disable your caching via .htaccess. I hope I got your question correctly. If not please correct me

Comment: Since those pages are still really basic i am able to test it in the browser. I'm using safari and deactivated caching in order to test if it is a caching problem. However, the problem persists and i really don't understand why. Other pages don't have this problem, i'm stumbled why..

Comment: I tried your .htaccess solution, however, note that i am using Cordova so i'm not sure where to put the file? I put it in the `www` folder where my `html` files are, however, this did not solve the problem (tried it in the browser and on my phone as well).

Comment: my bad, forget the htaccess solution. Actually with versioning you should be able to get the fresh content.

Comment: I agree with you, however, other pages don't show this behavior and even with caching deactivated it does not work. Hence, i suppose it's not a caching problem but really the javascript file not getting loaded when navigating (for some reason).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't comment for now. I try to suggest that try to put your needed `JS` in your `index.html` or `index. blah blah blah`. Or put it inside the loaded `view/page`

Cheers

Comment: I consider inline scripts to be bad practice, especially for large files. In my case the javascript code is about 200 loc, which would be awful if put inline in the html file.